# Google Maps API Store Locator example with MarkerClusterer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I recently created a store locator using the "Google Maps API Store Locator" [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#createmap).

Now I'm trying to implement the [MarkerClusterer Library](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/docs/reference.html) so that I can display a large single marker instead of multiple markers when users are zoomed out at a certain distance.

When I add the output code:

```
... 

GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {

var xml = GXml.parse(data);

var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

map.clearOverlays();

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

...
```

I get the following error:

> marker.getLatLng is not a function

Has anyone tried to implement this piece in the past?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to use some Google Maps v2 or possibly v1 code with the v3 api, hence you get the error 'getLatLng is not a function'..

Try the v3 marker cluster library:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

Here's an example:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html?